# Send multiple individualised emails via a limited number of SMTP clients

Tags: c#, multithreading, email

This is my first foray into multi-threading, and I'm keen to know if I have fallen into any traps or have room for optimisation/improvement.

Example usage:

> ```
> var success = new ConcurrentBag<CourseParticipant>();
> var fail = new ConcurrentBag<CourseParticipant>();
> using (var parallelEmails = new ParallelSmtpEmails())
> {
>      foreach (var cp in courseParticipants)
>      {
>         var mail = new MailMessage{
>             From = new MailAddress("from@example.com"),
>             To = cp.email,
>             Subject = "come and attend course",
>             BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html
>         }
>         string token = await GetRegistrationTokenAsync(cp);
>         mail.Body = $"<div><a href='example.com/register?userToken='{token}'>let me come</a></div>"
>         parallelEmails.Send(mail, s=> 
>         {
>             if (s == null)
>             {
>                 success.Add(cp);
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 fail.Add(cp);
>             }
>             mail.Dispose();
>         });
>      }
>      await parallelEmails.SendingComplete();
> }
> ```

In the code below, I am particularly wondering about the `RunWorker` method, the `do while` loop, and `if workList.TryGet`. If there is nothing in the worklist, this thread will remain looping until `CompletedAdding` is called or more emails are added. Is this looping an acceptable way to wait the thread?

Being an amateur, I am also grateful for any other code improvements or style points.

```
public class ParallelSmtpEmails : IDisposable
{
    BlockingCollection<MailTask> _workList;
    List<Task> _tasks;
    int _maxClientCount;

    public ParallelSmtpEmails(int maxSmtpClients = 5)
    {
         //removing the boundedCapacity := maxSmtpClients from BlockingCollection instantiator - the collection can be filled up without blocking
        _workList = new BlockingCollection<MailTask>(new ConcurrentQueue<MailTask>()); 
        _tasks = new List<Task>(maxSmtpClients);
        _maxClientCount = maxSmtpClients;        
    }

    public void CompletedAdding()
    {
        _workList.CompleteAdding();
    }

    public void Send(MailMessage message)
    {
        Send(message, null);
    }

    public void Send(MailMessage message, Action<SmtpException> onComplete)
    {
        _workList.Add(new MailTask() { Message = message, OnComplete = onComplete });
        if (_tasks.Count < _maxClientCount && _workList.Count > 0)
        {
            _tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(RunWorker));
        }
    }

    public Task SendingComplete()
    {
        CompletedAdding();
        return Task.WhenAll(_tasks);
    }

    public void RunWorker()
    {
        using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            do
            {
                MailTask m;
                if (_workList.TryTake(out m))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        client.Send(m.Message);
                        m.OnComplete?.Invoke(null);
                    }
                    catch (SmtpException ex)
                    {
                        m.OnComplete?.Invoke(ex);
                    }
                }
            } while (!_workList.IsCompleted);
        }
    }

    #region IDisposable
    bool _disposed;
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    ~ParallelSmtpEmails()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed)
            return;

        if (disposing)
        {
            // free other managed objects that implement
            // IDisposable only
            _workList.Dispose();
        }

        // release any unmanaged objects
        // set the object references to null

        _disposed = true;
    }
    #endregion //IDisposable

    private class MailTask
    {
        public MailMessage Message { get; set; }
        public Action<SmtpException> OnComplete { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Don't use `SmptClient.Send()`, use `SmptClient.SendMailAsync()` instead. It returns a `Task`.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/150768/41243).

Actually, I don't think you need this class at all.

*(I'm typing in a notepad, so this is untested and just to illustrate the concept.)*

```
var mailTasks = new List<Task>();
var client = new SmtpClient();

foreach(var participant in courseParticipants)
{
    var mail = new MailMessage
    {
        From = new MailAddress("from@example.com"),
        To = participant.email,
        Subject = "come and attend course",
        BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html
    }

    string token = await GetRegistrationTokenAsync(cp);
    mail.Body = $"<div><a href='example.com/register?userToken='{token}'>let me come</a></div>";

    mailTasks.Add(client.SendMailAsync(mail));
}

try
{
    await Task.WhenAll(mailTasks);
}
catch(AggregateException ex)
{
    //handle failures
}
```

This code is much simpler to understand, and therefore maintain.

---

One last thing before I go: Are you *absolutely certain* that `GetRegistrationTokenAsync()` will always return a url safe string?

> ```
> string token = await GetRegistrationTokenAsync(cp);
> mail.Body = $"<div><a href='example.com/register?userToken='{token}'>let me come</a></div>";
> ```

You should probably be Url encoding the token.