# Using SendAsync to send multiple emails

Tags: c#, performance, asynchronous, email

My method for sending emails with `Send()` is getting very slow when I send more than ten messages.

Sample

> 1 (1 sec)
>
> 2 (2 sec)
>
> 3 (4 sec)
>
> 4 (8 sec) and so on...

so I started to try `SendAsync()`

```
public Boolean sendSMTPMail(string subject, string body, customer[] recipients, string attachmentFileName = null)
{
    string css = "<style>*{font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}</style>";
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    //some client settings..

    MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
    mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mm.From = new MailAddress(MainForm.from, MainForm.fromName, Encoding.UTF8);
    mm.Subject = subject;

    foreach (var recipient in recipients)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
        mm.To.Clear();
        mm.To.Add(new MailAddress(recipient.getEmail()));
        mm.AlternateViews.Add(getEmbeddedImages(css + doReplacements(body, recipient)));

        try
        {
            //client.Send(mm);
            client.SendAsync(mm, "userToken");
            //client.SendMailAsync(mm);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Additional Information about my methods:**

`getEmbeddedImages` replaces `imagePath` with needed `cid:xxxx` and adds the image so it can be sent as a part of the email and not only as attachment.

`doReplacements` replaces strings in my body to get the email text more recipient specific:

```
Hello my name is %name%,
I am %age% years old.
```

will be translated to

```
Hello my name is John Doe,
I am 100 years old.
```

**Questions:**

1. Is this the right way to do it?
2. Is it important to send different userTokens?
3. For what is this token needed anyway? Obviously it doesn't matter what I fill in there.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50842/discussion-on-question-by-dwza-using-sendasync-to-send-multiple-emails).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the SendAsync docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h(v=vs.110).aspx):

> After calling SendAsync, you must wait for the e-mail transmission to
>   complete before attempting to send another e-mail message using Send
>   or SendAsync.

So no, this may not work properly. You need to register an event handler on the `SmtpClient.SendCompleted` event so that you know the message has sent successfully.

I'm going to be frank about this, the SmtpClient has an *awful* API. Your confusion is not your fault.

Your best bet would be to create a dictionary of recipients to use as a queue.

- Send the first message and pass the dictionary key in as the token.
- When the message completed event occurs, use the token to remove the recipient from the dictionary and send the next message.
- Repeat until the queue is empty.

This is going to be a slow, fairly synchronous process, so you may want to spin up a background thread or task to run this on, if your program has other work to do while this is going on.

I *really* encourage you to thoroughly read through the documentation I linked to. It's an old part of the framework and not very user (or async) friendly.

---

Or forget all that and just use the newer [SendMailAsync(MailMessage) method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193922(v=vs.110).aspx).

Just be sure to *await* the result.

```
    try
    {
        await client.SendMailAsync(mm);
    }
```

Which means that you'll need to modify the signature of your method to be compatible with async/await.

Comment: i know that i have to bind the complete event... but the documentation says `This method does not block the calling thread and allows  the caller to pass an object to the method that is invoked when the operation completes.` My recipients are stored in kind of a object array (see foreach) having email, username, customernumber and stuff like that. Why does sending will take long ?

Comment: Because it has to connect to your smtp server, which in turn needs to actually send the message, receive a receipt from the receiving server, then send that confirmation back to your application. That's 1-2-3-4 (possibly many more) jumps over several networks. That's a slow operation, no way around it.

Comment: @Dwza I cannot encourage you enough to go read the example code in the docs and think about how you could create a long running, yet asynchronous, process using events and a queue.

Comment: I think part of the confusion is that the method is named `SendAsync`, but it doesn't return a Task, so it can't be awaited like most newer methods with that name. This API does asynchronous the old fashioned way.

Comment: So is it the same if i simply use SendMailAsync() ?

Comment: That's a good call @Dwza. That seems to be a newer method. It returns a task. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193922(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: no it works like a charm :D thank you for these hints

Answer (score 1):

Some quick remarks:

- Don't abbreviate needlessly: `mm`.
- If `customer` is a class, why isn't its name PascalCased?
- Methods should be PascalCase: `sendSMTPMail`, `getEmbeddedImages`.
- [Do capitalize only the first character of acronyms with three or more characters, except the first word of a camel-cased identifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx). So `Smtp` instead of `SMTP`.

Comment: This is matter for a comment, not for an answer.

Comment: **1)** But I want to    
**2)** Because I can :P
**3)** Should, not must! 
I also think thats wrong. In my mind Classes are PascalCase and methods are camelCase.
**4)** I actually more stick with PSR instead of MS conventions since I am coding in othere languages as well :D
But thx *(even doe my thanks came late after 8 years :D )*